# Appending list(iterable) to empty list returns empty list

Tags: python-3.x, list, grouping, python-itertools

can someone explain why this isn't working? I want to create a list (list0) containing multiple lists, in this example grouped by the first word (Test0, Test1, Test2).

```
from itertools import groupby
list0 = []
list1 = ['Test0 A.csv', 'Test1 A.csv', 'Test1 B.csv', 'Test2 A.csv', 'Test2 B.csv', 'Test2 C.csv']
for k,g in groupby(list1, key=lambda x: x.split(' ')[0]):
    print(list(g))
    list0.append(list(g))
    print(list0)
```

Output becomes:

```
['Test0 A.csv']
[[]]
['Test1 A.csv', 'Test1 B.csv']
[[], []]
['Test2 A.csv', 'Test2 B.csv', 'Test2 C.csv']
[[], [], []]
```

Any help is appreciated!
/David

Comment: You see what's going on if you duplicate the line `print(list(g))`: Iterating over the iterator(!) exhausts it. Save the list in a temporary name, print it and append it.

Comment: I see! I had some other errors in my code and used the print to debug, and then nothing worked anymore. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g` is an iterator, not (just) an iterable. Therefore, iterating over it is not necessarily reproducible; in this case iterating over the iterator exhausts it.  You can see the effect of this by duplicating your call to print:

```
for k,g in groupby(list1, key=lambda x: x.split(' ')[0]):
    print(list(g))
    print(list(g))
    list0.append(list(g))
    print(list0)
```

Output:

```
['Test0 A.csv']
[]
[[]]
['Test1 A.csv', 'Test1 B.csv']
[]
[[], []]
['Test2 A.csv', 'Test2 B.csv', 'Test2 C.csv']
[]
[[], [], []]
```

---

To solve this, save the list you created from it into a name that you can print and append:

```
for k,g in groupby(list1, key=lambda x: x.split(' ')[0]):
    g_list = list(g)
    print(g_list)
    list0.append(g_list)
    print(list0)
```